# Formula for Average Percentage Increase/Decrease from chronological data range.

Tags: average, data-analysis

Let's say I have the following data:

$$1,2,3,1,4,0,6,4,3,2,46,7,5,7$$

I'd like to get a percentage based off some sort of average change of the data (in the order) to get an idea of what % the data appears to be increasing/decreasing on average.

The data above is obviously increasing from start to finish (with a few random changes). But what is the average increase in a percentage format?

My first thought was to take the difference between each consecutive number pair (ie: $2-1 = 1, 3-2 = 1, 1-3 = -2,$ etc), then taking the averages of all these difference values. This might get what I want. But I was wondering if there was some more clever formulas that might do this better.

Cheers!

Comment: Percent change suggests you are looking at multiplicative changes, but no multiplier of $0$ yields $6$.  Additive changes are fine of course.  Also, I assume you omitted a comma in what reads "$46$".

Comment: @lulu I've thrown in a large number to demonstrate a 'spike' in values which might skew the data slightly.

Comment: Ok. Of course with such a short series it has a very strong effect.

Comment: Are you looking for some sort of exponential growth fit? For example, you go from 1 to 7 in 13 intervals. So you would have 1*(1+p)^13=7, and then 100*p would be your percentage growth rate per interval. There are more sophisticated approaches if this is what you were aiming at.

Comment: @Samadin Not sure if I am looking for exponential or not. I'd simply like a final number which represents the overall average percentage of change from in the data set. Thus giving me an idea of 1) if the data is increasing or decreasing and 2) on average, by how much (% format). It's been a really long time since i've done any sort of sin/cos/tan\ ;)

Comment: Hmm, so the process you mentioned in your post is the same as taking the ( (final number)-(initial number) ) / (number of intervals). This may be all you need, but imagine a sequence like 10,100,1000,10000,1. That method will give a negative average increase, which is accurate, but may not be the best description of the overall trend.

Comment: @Samadin It sounds like you know exactly what i'm trying to get to. As you said, only use the first and last doesn't give an accurate description of the overall change trend.

Comment: In this case, the best method depends on the data itself. If your data is more or less linear with some random ups/downs, a [linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) may be appropriate. That's one of the simplest models to implement.

Comment: @Samadin That does look like a perfect graphical representation of what i'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @Samadin I assume, in terms of getting a number, 'slope' is what I am looking for to indicate the % change.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58662/discussion-between-samadin-and-david).

Answer (score 0):

A good measure of this is check the highest increasing chain.

$100*$(No of elements in the highest increasing chain)$/$No of total elements
is a good measure of percentage of increasing trend in a particular data.

By the largest increasing chain of the sequence 
$a_1,a_2,a_3,....a_n$, what I meant is a subsequence with largest cardinality which is increasing, that is a subsequence $a_{k_1},a_{k_2},....a_{k_m}$
such that $k_1<k_2<....<k_m$ and $a_{k_1}<a_{k_2},....<a_{k_m}$

Comment: In that case, how do you decide what is in the sub sequence?